# Unity freezes when laptop screen is closed

Tags: 12.04, unity, laptop, freeze, asus

I have an Asus laptop running Ubuntu 12.04. It's configured to do nothing when the laptop screen is closed. But sometimes, when I close the screen and when I reopen it, after I move the mouse to reactivate the screen, my Unity interface is frozen and I can't click on anything. I can move the cursor, and if there's a music playing it keeps playing, but I can't click on anything. I can open a bash shell typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, but there I don't know what to do, I can only login and type `sudo reboot` to reboot the machine...

Is there someone that has the same problem or that knows the solution?

Comment: You should [report this as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).